# MS-Access: Import database from access to access

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to import a table from access database to other access database.
But I don't want to import exactly, I have diferents fields

Courses Table 1

```
------------------------------
id | name | cost | other_field
------------------------------
1  | C012 | 250  | data
```

Courses Table 2

```
------------------------------
id | name | cost  
------------------------------
1  | C012 | 250
```

I have all data into Courses 1 and I want to import this table to another table, but just some fields.

Can you help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Link to `Table1` in `OtherAccessDb`:

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "Microsoft Access", "C\:Path\OtherAccessDb.accdb", acTable, "Table1", Table1
```

Now Pass the data. If you have created `Table2`, Use SQL statement to insert to it data from `Table1`:

```
DoCmd.Execuet "INSERT INTO Table2 (id, name, cost) SELECT id, name, cost FROM Table1"
```

If you have not created `Table2`, Use SQL statement to create it, insert to it data from `Table1`:

```
DoCmd.Execuet "SELECT INTO Table2 id, name, cost FROM Table1
```

If you don't need the link to `Table1` for other use, it is recommended you remove it:

```
CurrentDb.TableDefs.Delete "Table1"
```

**Note:** this answer displays the process using VBA code. If it is a one time job, you can create a link, and a SQL query using the Access ribbon.